# Shrink array. Data lost when copy

Tags: c++

I have so that you can delete a value from an array and when you do that all the other values should move so there is no gap in the array. I after the function runs and I want to do something with the new array the program crash and it can't find the values.

sectionKey is the index that will be deleted.

```
void Content::DeleteSection(int sectionKey){
    int y = 0;
    Section * tempArray = new Section[count-1];

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(i != sectionKey){
            tempArray[y] = sections[i];
            y++;
        }
    }
    delete[] sections;
    sections = tempArray;
}
```

The code part where it crash after I have made the array smaller.

```
void Content::Save(Content* content, QString filePath){

    QFile file(filePath);
    file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    //Format data
    QXmlStreamWriter stream(&file);
    stream.setAutoFormatting(true);
    stream.writeStartDocument();

    stream.writeTextElement("numberOfSections",QString::number(content->count));
    for(int i = 0; i < content->count; i++){
        stream.writeStartElement("Section");
        stream.writeTextElement("name",content->sections[i].name); // Crasch
        stream.writeEndElement();
    }
    //Save data

    stream.writeEndDocument();

}
```

And the error I get is

> The inferior stopped because it triggered an exception.
>
> Stopped in thred 0 by: Exception at 0x65910dbc, code: 0x0000005: read access violaation at: 0x0, flags=0x0

And Sections consist of this which isn't much.

```
class Section
{
public:
    Section();
    Section(int key);
    Section(const Section& other);
    ~Section();
    QString name;
private:
    int key;
};
```

Comment: where does it crash, and what's the error?

Comment: Time to debug the problem, then

Comment: Updated my answer with the code the error comes

Comment: Not helpfull :) Give the number of the offending line or smth.

Comment: line 14 in the second code. Where I have commented with //crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as if you should decrement count as part of the delete operation.

```
    delete[] sections;
    count--;                    // Decrease size
    sections = tempArray;
}
```

If you don't then you will read beyond array limits and things will fail (crash).

Comment: Yea that was the problem changed from count - 1 to --count when i declare the new array.

Answer (score 2):

You clearly want to use dynamic array, thus go on and use one - `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
vec.erase(vec.begin() + n); //removes n-th element
```

Otherwise you are recreating functionality that is already created and supplied in standard library.

Of-course your use-case may be very specific and you really NEED to use your plain old array, but then hey - do some debugging with breakpoints and such.